# Is there a way to set up multiple Local Go Modules, so they can run inside one Docker container without pulling from Github?

Tags: docker, go, import, module, local

So my goal is to set up a local development environment with multiple Go services (all as independent modules) running in multiple docker containers and one Go module, which all services can use to start a new service with connection to the database etc. without repeating this code in every module/service.

So my structure would look something like that (in $GOPATH/src/github.com/name/backend/):

```
|--services
|  |--service1
|     |--Dockerfile
|     |--main.go
|     |--go.mod
|  |--service2
|     |--Dockerfile
|     |--main.go
|     |--go.mod
|--serviceHelper
|  |--serviceHelper.go
|  |--go.mod
```

My Dockerfile currently is just a plain Dockerfile for Go:

```
FROM golang:alpine AS build-env
WORKDIR /backend
ADD . /backend
RUN cd /backend && go build -o service1

FROM alpine
RUN apk update && \
   apk add ca-certificates && \
   update-ca-certificates && \
   rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
WORKDIR /backend
COPY --from=build-env /backend/service1 /backend
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["./service1"]
```

My go.mod file also is just:

```
module github.com/name/backend/services/service1

go 1.17
```

The problem I'm having now though is that you either have to pull a module from a github repository, which I don't want to do, or put the serviceHelper code in every single module for the services, which I don't want to do either.

I work with VSCode and have since learned that you have to put single modules into single workspace folders. Still I can't manage to configure the modules locally to import both normal packages like `github.com/gorilla/mux` and also my local package in one service. I work with an Apple M1, I hope that might not cause problems as well.

How do I need to configure the go.mod files, the Docker files and the Go imports so that I can both debug Go normally in the editor (i.e. that the serviceHelper module is not just loaded into the Docker container directly), and also run everything locally without having to source the serviceHelper from github?

**Update:**
I already tried a lot of variants, but with this one (thank you for your answer colm.anseo), I got the least error messages but it still tries to connect to github, which I don't want.
So the updated go.mod file looks like:

```
module github.com/name/backend/services/service1

go 1.17

require (
    github.com/name/backend/serviceHelper v1.0.0
    github.com/gorilla/mux v1.8.0
)

replace github.com/name/backend/serviceHelper => ../../serviceHelper
```

When I then try to build a new go.sum with `go mod tidy`, this error occures (and that's the error I meant with "and also run everything locally without having to source the serviceHelper from github", because I got this error before):

```
github.com/name/backend/servicehelper: cannot find module providing package github.com/name/backend/servicehelper: module github.com/name/backend/servicehelper: git ls-remote -q origin in /Users/myName/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/...: exit status 128:
        ERROR: Repository not found.
        fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

        Please make sure you have the correct access rights
        and the repository exists.
```

I don't want it to connect to github, I just want it to run locally. With the help of the answer from colm.anseo I think I know how to create a working Dockerfile, so that's not a concern anymore.

Comment: You want to use one module in another and don't want to push and pull to GitHub?

Comment: I think you are confusing *building* a Docker image with *running* a Docker container. The two are separate processes. *Building* will have to pull third-party reps from the internet - whether that is done inside a multi-stage docker build or compiled locally on your machine and copied to a Docker image - makes no difference and there's no way around that.

Comment: Thank you for your fast responses. No, I know that I have to pull all the third party reps. But I don't want to have to pull my own module in order to use it inside of the docker containers from the services.

Comment: So yes, I want to use one local module inside of another module which is running inside of a docker container.

Comment: You'll probably be interested in this feature, still under development: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/45713

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
replace github.com/name/backend/serviceHelper => ../../serviceHelper
...
github.com/name/backend/servicehelper: cannot find module
```

Imports are case sensitive. I'd recommend making everything lower case, in your import, the replace statement, and the go.mod file of the package you're importing.

Comment: Man, you are my hero. It works. `go mod tidy` ran without a problem and all the dependecies are working. Now I just have to use the answer by colm.anseo to build a working Dockerfile. Such a small thing, and I didn't find it 

Answer (score 0):

If you are not ready to publish your code to an internet git repo (like `github.com`) you can use the [replace directive](https://golang.org/ref/mod#go-mod-file-replace) in your `go.mod`:

```
module github.com/me/my_app

go 1.17

require (
    github.om/gorilla/handlers v1.5.1
    github.com/me/my_srv1
)

replace github.com/me/my_srv1 => ./my_srv1
```

in your Go code you can import this code as if it came from the internet:

```
// go code
import (
    "github.om/gorilla/handlers"
    "github.com/me/my_srv1"
)
```

In your Docker context you will have to make sure the directory `./my_srv1` is copied and accessible in the same relative path as your `go build`.

`go build` in conjunction with the `go.mod` will then pull the `gorilla/mux` package from the internet - but use the local development directory as a substitute for your (yet to be published) repo.

Comment: I already did that but I think I used the replace statement the wrong way. Now I use it like `replace github.com/name/backend/serviceHelper => ../../serviceHelper` (you can see my folder structure in my original question), but it still tries to pull from github because I get the error: `not found: github.com/name/backend@v0.0.0-...: invalid version: git fetch -f origin refs/heads/*:refs/heads/* refs/tags/*:refs/tags/* in /tmp/gopath/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/...: exit status 128: fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled`.

Comment: Are you sure you are copying `go.mod`; `go.sum` into your Docker build - as well as the relative path `../../serviceHelper` so the build will find it in that relative path?

Comment: Oh, I should have mentioned that this error already happens locally on `go mod tidy`. So it is not even in the docker build.

Comment: You need to update your question with the updated state of you `go.mod` & (abbreviated) `go.sum` - things have obviously changed since your originally posed the question.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thank you. I updated the original question.

Comment: Thank you for your help too. I really appreciate it.